Doubt on compact space proof
The topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is compact and exists a compact subset $K$ that is not closed. I want to see that
$$
\mathcal{T}_{K^c} = \{ U \cup ( V \cap K^c) \: : \: U,V \in \mathcal{T} \}
$$
is strictly finer than $\mathcal{T}$ and prove that $(X,\mathcal{T_{K^c}})$ is compact.
It is easy to see that $\mathcal{T} \subsetneq \mathcal{T}_{K^c}$. In fact, let $U \in \mathcal{T}$, then with $V=\emptyset$ we have that $U=U \cup (\emptyset \cap K^c) \in \mathcal{T}_{K^c}$. Furthermore, $K^c \in \mathcal{T_{K^c}}$ but $K^c \notin \mathcal{T}$.
Now, in order to prove that $(X,\mathcal{T_{K^c}})$ is compact, we have to see that $\forall \mathcal{U}$ open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover. Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $X$, then
$$
X = \underset{U \in \mathcal{U}}\cup U = \underset{i \in I}\cup (U_i \cup (V_i \cap K^c)) = (\underset{i \in I}\cup U_i) \cup ((\underset{i \in I}\cup V_i) \cap K^c)
$$
Therefore, $K \subset \underset{i \in I}\cup U_i$ and as K is compact, there exists a finite subcover such that $K \subset \cup_{j=1}^{n} U_j$. Then,
$$
X = (\cup_{j=1}^{n} U_j) \cup ((\underset{i \in I}\cup V_i) \cap K^c)
$$
Now, I fail to see how can I obtain a finite subcover of $(\underset{i \in I}\cup V_i) \cap K^c$, such that all of them are in $\mathcal{U}$. The book I am following states
$$
X = \cup_{j=1}^{n} U_j \cup K^c
$$
which indeed is true, but I fail to see why $K^c \in \mathcal{U}$.
I'd really appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance, best regards!

As you say, a finite subset of your index set, $I_1\subseteq I$, is enough so that $K\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I_1}U_i$. We would then only require to prove that $\exists I_2\subseteq I$ finite, so that $K^C\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I_2}\left(U_i\cup \left(V_i\cap K^C\right)\right)$.
Firstly, we observe that it suffices to prove the existance of such an index set so that $K^C\subseteq\bigcup_{i\in I_2}\left(U_i\cup V_i\right)$, where we observe that $\{U_i\cup V_i|i\in I\}$ is clearly an open covering of $X$ in the original topology, as the corresponding sets are bigger than those of $\mathcal{U}$.
But then, the conclusion follows from the fact that $X$ is compact, as the finite set of indices such that $X$ is covered by the associated finite subcover suffices, because if the subcover is able to cover the whole of $X$, it is with more reason able to cover $K^C\subseteq X$.
